# Combining non-overlapping binary rasters with ArcGIS Raster Calculator?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.3, raster-calculator, con

The issues I keep seeing depend on **unique** combinations of values.

I have three rocktype raster layers for area and they are edge-to-edge (they do not overlap). They each have "VALUE" fields and "COUNT" fields. There's one row of data for each attribute table where "VALUE"=1 where the rock type exists. I guess this is like mask.

What I need to do is combine these three rasters into one with raster calculator using this logic.

rocktype1==1, output value=1

rocktype2==1, output value=2

rocktype3==1, output value=3

Here's what I've tried:

```
Con("rocktype2"==1, 2) | Con("rocktype1"==1, 1) | Con("rocktype3"==1, 3)
Con("paleo"==1, 2, Con("precamb"==1, 1, Con("tert_quat"==1, 3))) 
Combine(["rocktype2","rocktype1","rocktype3"])
rocktype1 + rocktype2 + rocktype3
```

I continuously get a blank output raster. What am I doing wrong here?

I'm using ArcMap 10.3.

Comment: (Raster1==1)+(raster2==1)*2+(raster3==1)*3

Comment: this expression produced another blank raster output.

Comment: Set environment extent to union of inputs.

Comment: I've set that parameter in processing extent in envinronment settings and it still produces a blank raster

Comment: What does Raster==1 produces?

Comment: that produces a raster identical to the raster referenced in the expression (still using "union of inputs")

Comment: so the rest of your raster IS nodata?

Comment: yes that is correct

Comment: ~IsNull(Raster1)+2*(~IsNull(Raster2))+3*(~IsNull(Raster3))

Comment: That's it! I'll have to read up on IsNull function. Thanks Felix!

Comment: This might be better for understanding Con(IsNull(r1),1,0)+Con(IsNull(r2),2,0)+Con(IsNull(r3,3,0)

Comment: Post it as solution to your own question and check as solved. This is normal

Comment: By "check as solved" I think @FelixIP means for you to click the green Accept button next to whichever answer helped you the most.  You may not be able to do that immediately which is to give a chance for more answers to come in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per comment by FelixIP, this expression worked for me:

```
~IsNull("precamb")+2*(~IsNull("paleo"))+3*(~IsNull("tert_quat"))
```

Comment: Mark it as solved please to help others

Answer (score 1):

The raster calculator is working a different way.

First you need to declare your OutRaster that will be saved:

OutRas = Con(...)

Your expression may probably look like this (like your second try, but not sure why you set other names there):

OutRas = Con("rocktype1"==1,1,Con("rocktype2"==2,2,Con("rocktype3"==1,3)))

Comment: Oops sorry those are the actual names of the rocktypes, just forgot to change them for this purpose. I tried the expression you suggested and the output was only rocktype1.